# Generar notación romana a partir de un patron en Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy creando una clase de utilidad de conversión de sistema numérico arábico a notación romana. Quiero realizar una función que, a partir de un patrón de tipo "?X?", devuelva todas las combinaciones posibles de caracteres que coincidan con el patrón. Los caracteres válidos para la cadena son MCMXCIV, I, V, X, L, C, D, M y ?.

Comparto mi conversor de sistema númerico arábico a notación romana en swift.

```swift
class RomanConverter {
    
    func romanToInt(_ s: String) -> Int {
        let romanValues: [Character: Int] = [
            "I": 1, "V": 5, "X": 10, "L": 50, "C": 100, "D": 500, "M": 1000
        ]

        var result = 0
        var prevValue = 0

        for char in s.reversed() {
            if let value = romanValues[char] {
                if value < prevValue {
                    result -= value
                } else {
                    result += value
                }
                prevValue = value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
    
    
    func intToRoman(_ n: Int) -> String {
        guard n > 0 && n < 4000 else {
            return "Number must be between 1 and 3999"
        }
        
        var returnString = ""
        let arabicNumbers = [1000,  900, 500,  400, 100,   90,  50,   40,  10,    9,   5,    4,  1]
        let romanLetters  = [ "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"]

        var num = n
        for (ar, rome) in zip(arabicNumbers, romanLetters) {
            let repeats = num / ar
            returnString += String(repeating: rome, count: repeats)
            num %= ar
        }

        return returnString
    }
}
```

Y la función de generación de números romanos mediante patrón, que no funciona corerctamente

```swift
    func generateRomanNumbersWithPattern(pattern: String) -> [String] {
        var romanNumbers: [String] = []

        for number in 1...4999 {
            let romanNumber = intToRoman(number)

            // Reemplazar "?" con "[IVXLCDM]*" en el patrón
            let regexPattern = pattern.replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: "[IVXLCDM]*")

            if let _ = romanNumber.range(of: "^" + regexPattern + "$", options: .regularExpression) {
                romanNumbers.append(romanNumber)
            }
        }
        let stringLength = pattern.count
        let filteredStrings = romanNumbers.filter { $0.count == stringLength }

        return filteredStrings
    }
```

Mis pruebas si pongo solo `?` no me devuelve todos `I,V,X,L,C,D,M`

Comment: En esta parte `romanNumbers.filter { $0.count == stringLength }`  estás filtrando todos los valores que tengan longitud  = 1 y devuelve `["I", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"]`